# How to connect leafs and returning a List for nodes around the BST

Tags: c#, algorithm

This is my implementation for BST (Binary Search Tree). Can Anyone help me to create two methods, one to Connect Leafs and one to return a List of Nodes around the Tree, for example: [Connecting Leaf Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfsNt.png) In this picture it shows how the leafs should be connected, [Nodes that should be stored in List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msBR3.png) and the way the nodes stored in List need to be in this way where the root is the first element and going to the left passing down to leafs going back to root from the right. In my example it should be 8(root), 3, 1, 4, 7, 13, 14, 10, 8(root).
Thank You!

```
**class Node
{
    private int VL;
    private int Niv;
    public Node Parent, LC, RC;

    public Node()
    {
        this.Parent = this.LC = this.RC = null;
        this.Niv = -1;
    }
    public Node(int x)
    {
        this.VL = x;
        this.Parent = this.LC = this.RC = null;
        this.Niv = -1;
    }

    public int Vlera
    {
        get { return this.VL; }
        set { this.VL = value; }
    }

    public int Niveli
    {
        get { return this.Niv; }
        set { this.Niv = value; }
    }

}

class BSTree
{
    public Node Root;
    private int MaxNiv;

    public BSTree()
    {
        this.Root = null;
        this.MaxNiv = -1;
    }

    public void Insert(int x)
    {
        Node tmp = new Node(x);
        if (this.Root == null)
        {
            tmp.Niveli = 0;
            this.Root = tmp;
        }
        else InsertNode(tmp);

        if (tmp.Niveli > this.MaxNiv) MaxNiv = tmp.Niveli;

    }
    public void ConnectLeafs()
    {
        //TODO
    }
    public List<T> ReturnNodesAroundTheTree()
    {
        //TODO
    }
    public Node GoTo_Node(Node nd)
    {
        return GoTo_Node_Rec(this.Root, nd);
    }
    public Node GoTo_Node(int x)
    {
        return GoTo_Node_Rec(this.Root, x);
    }

    private Node GoTo_Node_Rec(Node root, Node nd)
    {
        if (root.Vlera == nd.Vlera) return root;
        if (root.Vlera > nd.Vlera) return GoTo_Node_Rec(root.LC, nd);
        else return GoTo_Node_Rec(root.RC, nd);
    }
    private Node GoTo_Node_Rec(Node root, int x)
    {
        if (root.Vlera == x) return root;
        if (root.Vlera > x) return GoTo_Node_Rec(root.LC, x);
        else return GoTo_Node_Rec(root.RC, x);
    }

    private void InsertNode(Node nd)
    {

        Node tmp = InsertRecNode(this.Root, nd.Vlera);

        if (nd.Vlera >= tmp.Vlera) tmp.RC = nd;
        else tmp.LC = nd;
        nd.Parent = tmp;
        nd.Niveli = nd.Parent.Niveli++;
        //if (nd.Niveli > this.MaxNiv) MaxNiv = nd.Niveli;

    }

    private Node InsertRecNode(Node root, int x)
    {

        if (x >= root.Vlera)
            if (root.RC != null) return InsertRecNode(root.RC, x);
            else return root;
        else
            if (root.LC != null) return InsertRecNode(root.LC, x);
        else return root;
    }
    private bool IsRoot(Node nd)
    {
        if (nd.Parent == null) return true;
        return false;

    }
    private bool IsLeaf(Node nd)
    {
        if (nd.LC == null && nd.RC == null) return true;
        return false;
    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way to do this.  I created a List of all the node.  When you create a new node add node to list.  See code below

```
    class BSTree
    {
        public Node Root;
        private int MaxNiv;
        private List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();

        public BSTree()
        {
            this.Root = null;
            this.MaxNiv = -1;
        }

        public void Insert(int x)
        {
            Node tmp = new Node(x);
            nodes.Add(tmp);
            if (this.Root == null)
            {
                tmp.Niveli = 0;
                this.Root = tmp;
            }
            else InsertNode(tmp);

            if (tmp.Niveli > this.MaxNiv) MaxNiv = tmp.Niveli;

        }
        public void ConnectLeafs()
        {
            //TODO
        }
        public List<Node> ReturnNodesAroundTheTree()
        {
            return nodes.Where(x => IsLeaf(x)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ty for comment, that method returns a list of leafs (extra help :)), instead of returning a list with the requirements that I had mention in the description. Can u bring with another solution for returning nodes around the tree + how can leafs connect with each other (look in description for more information).

Comment: I got you the answer to the first part which is to get a list of leaves.  The nodes around the BST consist of three parts 1) Leaves 2) All the left nodes from the root 3) All the right nodes from the root.